# Problem returning a web api when changing servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, webapi

The scenario I am facing is the following, a server migration was carried out at the company where I work and on the old server where it was hosted the Web API service worked normally, however when migrating to the new server this same service no longer works, when I go test the service at this url:

```
http://localhost:8041/Relatorio/Contrato/minhapagina.aspx?codcontrato=meucodigocontrato
```

when arriving at `PostAsync`, it show this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> 2 internal exceptions
>
> Unable to connect to remote server.
>
> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected component did not respond correctly after a period of time or the established connection failed because the connected host did not respond.

Could you help me with a solution?

I tried changing the host address for the solution but it didn't work.